# How to find old large files and generate metrics for directories containg those files

Tags: python, c, perl, sh

I am a hardware engineer working in a design department and we routinely generate directories with large amounts of data (both large files and directories that contain large numbers of small files). This data can hang around on the disk for quite a while and I am looking for a metric to identify directories with large amounts of old data in them as candidates for deletion.

The metric I have decided on is File Size (in M) * File Age (in days).

I have a working solution, but it is a combination of shell scripting and c and is neither maintainable, pretty nor elegant.

I am looking for ideas to improve the script.

The basic idea is to generate raw data on all the files using find

```
find $Dir -type f -exec stat -c "%s,%Y,%n" {} \; > rpt3
```

and then process that file in C to get a file (rpt3b) in the format

Metric,Age,Size,FileName

Metric is Age*Size

Age is number of days since file was modified

Size is size of file in M

FileName is name of file.

I then process this file to sum the metrics for each directory

```
for Directory in $( find /projects/solaris/implementation -maxdepth 4 -type d ) ; do
  Total=`grep $Directory/ rpt3a | sed -e 's?,.*??' | paste -sd+ - | bc`
  echo $Total,$Directory >> rpt3c
done
```

So the output is similar to a du, but it is the metric that is reported rather than the size taken on disk.

I could pull the last step into the C program, but I am looking for a solution that ideally works in one environment (doesn't have to be C, I am open to learning new languages).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the whole lot in Perl. Perl comes with two operators `-M` and `-s` which are respectively the age of the file in days and the size of the file in bytes. Age here being the script start time minus the file modification time, and also the `File::Find` module that mimics the find command.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

find(\&process, shift); # shift the start directory off @ARGV

sub process {
    # Lots of use of the magic _ file handle so we don't keep having to call stat()
    print( (-M _) * (-s _), ' ', -M _, ' ', -s _, " $File::Find::name\n")
        if -f $_;
}
```

Comment: @zdim That should work. now. It worked when I tested it last time because my initial directory was `..`

Comment: Thank you :)  (I would also round numbers and sort by metric)

Comment: @zdim I'll leave that as an exercise for the poster, they may want to do that by options :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. Was enough to get me going

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to extract the correct column from your extracted lines in place of `sed`. `cut -d, -f3` will extract the third column each separated by `,`.

With input:

```
10,2,5,a/b
20,4,5,a/c
30,2,15,b/d
40,4,10,a/d
```

command `grep a/ a.txt | cut -f3 -d, | paste -sd+ - | bc` will produce:

```
20
```

and command `grep b/ a.txt | cut -f3 -d, | paste -sd+ - | bc`:

```
15
```

Comment: Thanks - I agree with this

Answer (score 0):

Call `'python script.py startdir ~/somefile.txt'`.

You can use this as starting point:

```
import os
import sys
import time

def get_age_in_days(file_stats):
    """Calculate age in days from files stat."""
    return (time.time() - file_stats.st_mtime) // (60*60*24) 

def get_size_in_MB(file_stats):
    """Calculate file size in megabytes from files stat."""
    return file_stats.st_size / (1024 * 1024)

def metric(root,f):
    """Uses root and f to create a metric for the file at 'os.path.join(root,f)'"""
    fn = os.path.join(root,f)
    fn_stat = os.stat(fn) 
    age = get_age_in_days(fn_stat)
    size = get_size_in_MB(fn_stat)
    metric = age*size

    return [metric, age, size, fn] 

path = None
fn   = None
if len(sys.argv)==3:
    path = sys.argv[1]
    fn = sys.argv[2]
else:
    sys.exit(2)


with open(fn,"w") as output:  
    # walk directory recursivly and report anything with a metric > 1 
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        total_dict = 0
        for f in files:
            m = metric(root,f)

            # cutoff - only write to file if metric > 1
            if m[0] > 1: 
                total_dict += m[0]
                output.write(','.join(map(str,m))+"\n")
       output.write(','.join([str(total_dict), "total","dictionary",root])+"\n")

# testing purposes
# print(open(fn).read())
```

Example-file - (without cutoff - using https://pyfiddle.io/):

```
0.0,0.0,0.0011606216430664062,./main.py
0.0,0.0,0.0,./myfiles.txt
0.0,total,dictionary,./
```

You can look up any line that contains **`,total,dictionary,`**:  `0.0,total,dictionary,./` for dictionary-totals.